# Issuing connecting to AFP shares - "(Error) Volume: Root store set to FSOnly with matching create!"

Tags: network, error, afp

I'm having an issue connecting to my AFP shares on my unRAID server. After a couple of days of troubleshooting, I've narrowed down the issue to my Macbook and not the unRAID server.

I am able to connect to my AFP share, but before my Mac can connect it spins up all of my spun down unRAID disks (14 of them) and it takes a good minute or so before the share becomes available while this process happens. I've checked on another Macbook, and it's able to connect within a couple of seconds and only spin up the 1 hard drive it needs on my server. So it's definitely something with my Macbook that's querying for all the disk data from the server.

Here's the log from when I manually connect:

```
7/29/13 8:32:39.000 PM kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_mount: /Volumes/disk1, pid 879
7/29/13 8:32:39.000 PM kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_mount : succeeded on volume 0xffffff81d10f9008 /Volumes/disk1 (error = 0, retval = 0)
7/29/13 8:32:43.878 PM mds[54]: (Error) Volume: Root store set to FSOnly with matching create! (loaded:1)
```

Note the following:

```
7/29/13 8:32:43.878 PM mds[54]: (Error) Volume: Root store set to FSOnly with matching create! (loaded:1)
```

That's the part that differes on my Macbook compared to the Macbook that works correctly.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

- Repaired permissions
- Cleared Spotlight data and forced a refresh
- Cleared Keychain of all logins related to this server via AFP
- Deleted Finder preferences
- Uninstalled TotalFinder
- Uninstalled Alfred
- Uninstalled Pacifist
- Uninstalled OSXfuse
- Uninstalled BlueHarvest
- Uninstalled NFSManager
- Rebooted and tested after every change to try and find the culprit

Any ideas on what the exact issue could be? I've removed every application I can think of that could somehow tie into Finder or networking. I've googled for my exact error but couldn't find anything relevant.